# How does gem5 (Alpha) perform floating point operations?

Tags: fpu, gem5

I use gem5 to simulate the CPU architecture Alpha. How are floating point operations handled in gem5? Does it use a floating point unit? Do floating point operations consume more simulated time than integer?

Comment: Hi Apache, I have the following advice: 1) make your titles more precise, usually in the form of one complete full sentence, e.g.: "Do gem5 Alpha floating point operations consume more simulation time than integeres?" 2) Why don't you just try it out, run an se.py assembly example that just does one instruction then m5 dumpstats and m5exit? Also git grep the code a bit and GDB step debug the code. Then after doing that, if anything is left ununderstood, ask the more specific questions.

Comment: Fixed the title. Forgot to answer earlier, but I ran some simulations and they took the same time, no matter if int or float.